# Не отправляется форма из цикла

Tags: php, html

```
echo "<form action= method=\"post\" id=\"form_id\" title=$dsdasg>";
echo "<p><input type=\"text\" value=\"\" name=\"name\" id=\"a\"></p>";
echo "<p><input type=\"text\" name=\"text\" /></p>";
echo "<input id=\"submit\" type=\"button\" value=$dsdasg onclick=AjaxFormRequest('result_div_id', 'form_id', 'action_messages_us.php')/>";
echo "</form>";
```

Вама форма в цикле.
Где-то ошибка, т.е. не отправляет файлу пост данные в action_messages_us.php

Помогите мне правильно записать.

Answer (score 1):

Кавычки поставь так

```
echo "<input id=\"submit\" type=\"button\" value=$dsdasg onclick=\"AjaxFormRequest('result_div_id', 'form_id', 'action_messages_us.php')\"/>";
```